# wp_schedule_event does not call function associated to it

Tags: wordpress, cron

I am trying to schedule an event on hourly basis, that should store some data to a mlab database(mongo db), but the function is not getting called.

```
  class plug_Activator{
        public function  __construct() {

        add_action( 'my_hourly_event',  'tmpp' );
    }
    function activate() {

     if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'tmpp' ) ) {
             wp_schedule_event( time() - 3540, 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event');
     }
    }

    function tmpp(){
        $args= array(
    "website"=> "www.xyz.com",
    "post"=> "wasupp"
    );
    $response   = wp_remote_post( 'https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/todo/collections/todos?apiKey=xxxx', array(
    'headers'   => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
    'body'      => json_encode($args), 
    'method'    => 'POST'
        ));
    }}
```

Comment: _"but the function is not getting called"_ - and how exactly have you _verified_ that? Are you aware that this kind of "cron" mechanism requires activity on your page, and is that the case (did you have a user visiting the page, so that the mechanism could be triggered)?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, after activating the plugin im visiting the page myself. But still im not getting any data in the database

Comment: And your `activate` method is called where?

Comment: @CBroe That method is being called in another file, which calls this method when the plugin is activated.

function activate_plug() {
 require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/plug-activator.php';
 plug_Activator::activate();
}